# pyspark Dataframe API cast('timestamp') does not work on timestamp strings

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"createdAt":"2016-07-01T16:37:41-0400"}
{"id":2,"createdAt":"2016-07-01T16:37:41-0700"}
{"id":3,"createdAt":"2016-07-01T16:37:41-0400"}
{"id":4,"createdAt":"2016-07-01T16:37:41-0700"}
{"id":5,"createdAt":"2016-07-06T09:48Z"}
{"id":6,"createdAt":"2016-07-06T09:48Z"}
{"id":7,"createdAt":"2016-07-06T09:48Z"}
```

I am casting the `createdAt` field to timestamp as follows.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.json('data/test.json')
dfProcessed = df.withColumn('createdAt', df.createdAt.cast('timestamp'))

dfProcessed.printSchema()
dfProcessed.collect()
```

Output I get is as follows. I get None values for `createdAt`. What can I do to get the field retrieved as a proper timestamp?

```
root
 |-- createdAt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)

[Row(createdAt=None, id=1),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=2),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=3),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=4),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=5),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=6),
 Row(createdAt=None, id=7)]
```

Comment: BTW, what version of `Apache Spark` are you using?

Answer (score 6):

In order to simply cast a string column to a timestamp, the string column must be properly formatted.

To retrieve the "createdAt" column as a timestamp, you can write the UDF function that would convert the string

> "2016-07-01T16:37:41-0400"

to

> "2016-07-01 16:37:41"

and convert the "createdAt" column to a new format (don't forget to handle the timezone field).

Once you have a column containing timestamps as strings like "2016-07-01 16:37:41", a simple cast to timestamp would do the job, as you have it in your code.

You can read more about Date/Time/String Handling in Spark [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/apache-spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights.html).

Comment: Understood. Thanks. I was hoping to avoid UDFs and extra processing with something built in that takes care of it more efficiently. But, there does not seem to be one.